# Select mulitple lines without mouse in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I use MacOS. With other editors I've used, I can hold down <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> followed by a combination of <kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>n</kbd> to select multiple lines above or below the current point.  I've read through the keybindings under `Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Have you tried with `Cmd+Shift` instead of `Ctrl+Shift`?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I have but I can't choose the number of lines I select above/below.  I want to be able to press p once to move the shift selector up one line and press n to move the shift selector down one line

Comment: That's not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry but it's not possible to do what you want in Spyder.